# How to turn off logging for one URL log4j

Tags: java, logging, logback, dropwizard

I have project on old version of dropwizrd (0.9.3 where is no any log filter(https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-0.9.x/manual/core.html#logging)) and I want to disable log for one url.

I try to use it:

```
package com.pack.service.services;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply;


public class LogFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

  final static String SPAM_URL = "spam";

  @Override
  public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
    if (!event.getMessage().contains(SPAM_URL)) {
      return FilterReply.ACCEPT;
    } else {
      return FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
    }
  }
}
```

And in folder resources in log4j2.xml file I added it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR" >
    <Appenders>

        <Filter class="com.pack.service.services.LogFilter"/>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But I got the error:

2021-04-01 16:26:33,473 main ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "filter"

Answer (score 1):

You created a Filter for Logback and tried to use it in Log4j 2. They are completely different frameworks. You can look at the [MarkerFilter](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/filter/MarkerFilter.java) as an example of how to create a Filter for Log4j 2.

I should also point out that your configuration of the filter would be wrong. Log4j uses a Plugin system so you never specify class names in the configuration.

Having said that, you don't need to create your own filter. Just use Log4j's [RegexFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter). Or if you want to duplicate your code you could use the [ScriptFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#Script) and write the equivalent code in any Scripting language that supports JSR 223 such as Groovy.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <RegexFilter regex=".*healthcheck.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Comment: I see it in my console

Comment: 175.16.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021:10:13:18 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-",
175.16.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021:10:13:29 +0000] "GET /account HTTP/1.1" 200 149 "-"

Comment: If I am not mistaken those messages are tomcat’s access log messages. They don’t flow through Log4J unless you have configured tomcat to use it.

Comment: And what to do in my case?

Comment: Dropwizard use Jetty

Comment: According to https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html dropwizard uses Logback-access to log access requests. You would need to configure it to filter the messages you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it helped to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487749/logging-some-request-headers-with-dropwizard.