# Log4j2 RegexFilter ignore pattern

Tags: java, logging, console, log4j, dropwizard

This is my setting of log4j2.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n" />
            <RegexFilter regex=".*healthcheck.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But in the console I see it:

```
175.16.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021:10:13:18 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-",
175.16.0.1 - - [02/Apr/2021:10:13:29 +0000] "GET /account HTTP/1.1" 200 149 "-"
```

I want to hide log message witch contauns: healthcheck.

Comment: Are you certain that you rebuilt and redeployed your application after changing the above XML file?

Comment: Yea. I am sure.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907693/how-to-turn-off-logging-for-one-url-log4j/66915622#66915622

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off logging for one URL log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66907693/how-to-turn-off-logging-for-one-url-log4j)

Comment: No, this log was from Jetty, it helped to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487749/logging-some-request-headers-with-dropwizard